# Unvented gas heater shuts off (along with pilot) after running a while

Tags: heater

My new 30K btu Empire heater lights and burns fine but after a few minutes the flame gradually gets smaller then an audible click and it shuts off with the pilot going out too.  I haven't had chance to see if there is a fume buildup (my 850 sq ft house is pretty tight) but will try to see.  Anything else I should check or any ideas?  thanks

Comment: this will happen if it's unvented.  Who installed it this way?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Has it always behaved this way, or is this something new? Have you asked the installer? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I would check the pressure regulator and O2 sensor and flame sensor.

Comment: Why are you using an unvented heater?

Comment: Is this unit approved for indoor use?

Comment: You said new, is it still under warranty? Contact the MFG, even if listed as unvented something that large sounds crazy in a house.

Comment: In answer to the questions asked--yes it is new, installed by me per code, its unvented heater by choice so wind could not blow out the pilot while we are gone and we may be gone up to a month at a time. Unvented heaters are installed that way  by design.